Exclude the Newest Recent Post from their Category After New post Publish old post should be in their category at Home Page
For Avoid Duplication of Posts
Exclude the (Recent Newest Post) from their Category. But when a new post is published again in a similar or another category, the old post should be included again in their category and the new again excluded from their category.
Remember:
Only New Recent Post Exclude not 1st Post via Offset=>1 etc. Maybe post_not_in => will work Please Help.

$args=array(
'cat' => 735,
'orderby'=> 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=> 1, 
'offset'  => 0,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$the_query = new wp_query( $args );

